# trim (ltrim) cuts more

Tags: php, trim, substr, strlen

I have so many product names and brands. some of product names contain brand. some do not.
I want delete brand in product names.
`substr($name,strlen($brand));` caused problem at brandless names.

then I use this codes. but having problem again.

```
$brand = "Palm See";

$name = "Palm See Second Third ... "; 
$name = "See Season ... ";
$name = " See Sean Paul ";

$name = ltrim($name, $brand);

echo $name;     // cond Third ...   desired : Second Third ...
echo $name;     // son ...          desired : See Season ...
echo $name;     // n Paul           desired : See Sean Paul
```

Comment: `ltrim()` trims any of the ___letters___ in the list ('P' and 'a' and 'l' and 'm' and 'S' and 'e' and space in your example); not the specific string

Comment: `str_replace($brand, "", $name ); `  is okey?

Comment: Yes, `str_replace($brand, "", $name );` should work, but that will remove it from any part of the string. If you only want to remove it from the beginning, you should check that the string starts with `$brand` too. So you should do something like `if (strpos($name, $brand) === 0) { str_replace($brand, "", $name ); }`. The `if` here checks if the string starts with `$brand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have another look at how `ltrim` works:

> character_mask
>
> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply **list all characters that you want
>   to be stripped**. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

Try to remove it with `str_replace` instead and use trim only to remove any excess whitespace.